# Wordpress - Trying to retrieve only immediate children of custom post in loop

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, hierarchy

I have a custom post type called 'location' where the top level is state, second level down is city, and the third level is the actual location.

I've used the methods recommended [here](https://www.davidbrown-portfolio.com/wordpress-display-only-immediate-children-of-the-current-page/) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74063/getting-only-direct-child-pages-in-wordpress-with-get-pages) with no luck.   I've tried `get_pages()`, `get_posts()`, `get_children()` and it's either retrieving all children or retrieving all pages.

Here is my current code that is in the single template of the custom post type:

```
<?php $args = array(
                'child_of' => $post->ID, 
                'parent ' => $post->ID,
                'hierarchical' => 0,
                'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
                'sort_order' => 'asc',
            ); 
$locations = get_pages($args); ?>
    <?php
        foreach ($locations as $location):
            $title  = get_the_title($location->ID);
            $locale = get_field('location',$location->ID);
            $lat    = $locale['lat'];
            $lng    = $locale['lng'];
            $addy   = $locale['address'];
            $hours  = get_field('hours',$location->ID);
            $link   = get_the_permalink($location->ID);
    ?>
                <div class="location-single" data-lat="<?php echo $lat; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $lng; ?>">
                    <?php echo $title; ?>
                    <address><?php echo $addy; ?></address>
                    <time><?php echo $hours; ?></time>
                </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

EDIT: To cover all my bases, here is the code i'm using to register this custom post type.

```
function custom_post_type() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Locations', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Location', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Locations', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Location', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Locations Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Location Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Location:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Location', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Location', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Location', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Location', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Locations', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor','page-attributes' ),
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-location',
    'menu_position'         => 8,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'location', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

I'm inserting this into the the_content area using this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'location_content');  

function location_content( $content ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'location' ) ) {
        include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/location.php'; 
    }
    else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Could this be the issue?  Would it work better if I had a single template with this code on it instead?

EDIT: I've tried including this code and also the solution below in the single template file directly and it still returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for my usecase:

Instead of get_pages or get_posts I'm using new WP_Query.  that solved all my problems.  Thank you everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you're placing this code within the main WordPress loop so you have access to `$post`. If you're not, you'll need to declare with `global $post;`.

```
if ($post->post_parent) {

    $children = wp_list_pages(array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $post->post_parent, // child of only the parent page
        'echo' => 0, // do not echo
        'exclude' => $post->ID, // exclude the parent page from being added to array
        'post_type' => 'location' // only posts from the location post type
    ));

}

if ($children) {

    echo '<ul>' . $children . '</ul>';

}
```

You should be able to work this into your theme file and display any other info you want to outside of this. You could also do a `foreach()` loop on `$children` if you needed to in in case you need to add other content. I have this exact code running on a theme and it is working as intended. This does not get the page content, just the page titles with links. If I understand correctly, that's what you're looking for.

Comment: It is in the loop.   I've tried this solution and it returns nothing, not even the wrapping <ul> tags.

Comment: If you're not getting even the `<ul></ul>` then the `$children` variable is empty.

Comment: What do you think could be the problem? there are child posts, and I have added more details in the initial post on how I'm creating the post type and how I'm using this code.

Comment: You initially stated the post type name was "location", as in singular. Your code has it as "locations" as in plural. Try adding the s to location in this line of my code: `'post_type' => 'location'`.

Comment: Actually, disregard that last comment. I just noticed your `register_post_type()` line.

Comment: You should try using a single-location.php template file rather than trying to add this via a content filter. Are you certain your `include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/location.php'; ` line is returning the correct file path?

Comment: yes, I have commented code prior to the code above and it is returning that on the site.

Comment: I have done as requested and placed the code in the single template itself and it still returns nothing.

Comment: You have this wrapped in `if ($post->post_parent) { ... }` - if `post_parent` is 0 that won't meet that condition, so you may want to try  `if ($post->post_parent == 0) { ... }` or try it on a child post.

Comment: it's still returning all children and grandchildren.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it's a bit of a kludge, but it works...

```
<?php 
$post_id = $post->ID;
$level = count(get_post_ancestors( $post_id )) + 1;
switch($level) {
    case 1: ?>

<?php $args = array(  'child_of' => $post_id, 'parent ' => $post_id,'hierarchical' => 0, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'sort_order' => 'asc', 'post_type' => 'location',);
$mypages = get_pages( $args );
foreach( $mypages as $post ): ?>


    <?php 
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $level = count(get_post_ancestors( $post_id )) + 1;
    switch($level) {
        case 1: ?>


        <?php break;   
        case 2: ?>


<?php $location = get_field('location', $post->ID); ?>
<div class="location-single" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></a></h4>
<address><?php echo $location['address']; ?></address>
<time><?php the_field('hours',$post->ID); ?></time>
</div>


        <?php break;   
    }; ?>



<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php break;   
case 2: ?>

<?php $args = array(  'child_of' => $post_id, 'parent ' => $post_id,'hierarchical' => 0, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'sort_order' => 'asc', 'post_type' => 'location',);
$mypages = get_pages( $args );
foreach( $mypages as $post ): ?>


    <?php 
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $level = count(get_post_ancestors( $post_id )) + 1;
    switch($level) {
        case 1: ?>


        <?php break;   
        case 2: ?>

        <?php break;   
        case 3: ?>
    <?php $location = get_field('location', $post->ID); ?>
    <div class="location-single" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></a></h4>
<address><?php echo $location['address']; ?></address>
<time><?php the_field('hours',$post->ID); ?></time>
</div>


        <?php break;   
    }; ?>



<?php endforeach; ?>



<?php break;   
case 3: ?>

<?php $location = get_field('location', $post_id); ?>
<div class="location-single" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
<h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
<address><?php echo $location['address']; ?></address>
<time><?php the_field('hours'); ?></time>
</div>


<?php break;   
}; ?>
```

I'm basically looping through the loop and either printing nothing depending on the level of hierarchy.

EDIT: nevermind, it's not passing the post ID's into the nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Change `pet_pages` to `get_posts`, then modify the arguments you pass in.

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'location',
    'parent ' => $post->ID,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    // etc...
  ); 
  $locations = get_posts($args);
?>
```

Important here is to set the `post_type` to your custom post-type. If you set the `parent` config to the current `$post->ID`, not necessary to also set `child_of`.